# No MigrationSqlGenerator found for provider 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client'

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-migrations

I am using Code first approach for oracle with Entity framework 5.0.0.0.
i am getting below error during migration

```
No MigrationSqlGenerator found for provider 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client'. Use the SetSqlGenerator method in the target migrations configuration class to register additional SQL generators.
```

i have added Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.1.0 in solution and able to execute
 Enable-Migrations and add-migration Initial in package manage console but when i am going to excute update-database command then getting above error message and database and table is not created in oracle 11g.please let me know what should be do.it's correct dll  or we need to add additional changes.

Comment: I'm in the same situation